# Unable to enumerate MP3 tags in a Swift playground

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm trying to enumerate the ID3 tags in an MP3 file in an Xcode playground (using Swift) but all I get is an empty array. I've also tried 'nil' for the options (I also tried the one below out of desperation):

```
import Cocoa
import AVFoundation

var url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/marc/test.mp3")
let opts = [ AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: true ]
var asset = AVURLAsset(URL: url, options: opts)
var metaData = asset.commonMetadata

for item in metaData {
    print("key: \(item.commonKey), value: \(item.stringValue)")
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, and can anyone else get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playgrounds are sandboxed. You can't read from or write to the filesystem.

But you can read the files that are *inside* the Playground.

Open the project navigator:

> View > Navigators > Show Project Navigator

And *drop your MP3 in the `Resources` folder*.

Once it's there, drag the file *from inside the navigator to the source code area*: it will make an icon representing the file URL.

You can then use your code with this file:

```
let url = (the file icon dragged from the project navigator)

let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: url, options: nil)
let metaData = asset.commonMetadata

for item in metaData {
    if let key = item.commonKey, let value = item.stringValue {
        print("key: \(key), value: \(value)")
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That works a treat, although I don't get to see an icon but the full path to the sandboxed MP3 file (no biggie, it works). Good ol' sandboxing strikes again :-|